# TensorFlow: Restored variables seem random

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having an issue restoring some variables. I've already restored variables when I saved the whole model on a higher level, but this time I've decided to only restore a few variables.
Before the first session, I initialize the weights:

```
weights = {
'1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1], mean=0, stddev=tf.sqrt(2*1.67/(n_input+n_hidden_1))), name='w1')
}
weights_saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=weights)
```

Then, in a session, while I train the NN:

```
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:
[...]
weights_saver.save(sess, './savedModels/Weights/weights')
```

Then :

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(pathsToVariables + 'Weights/weights.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, pathsToVariables + 'Weights/weights')

    weights = 
    {
    '1': tf.Variable(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0"), name='w1', trainable=False)
    }

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(weights['1']))
```

But at this point, the weights restored seem to be random. And indeed, If I do `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` again, the weights will be different. As if, I restored the normal function of the initialization of the weights but not the trained weights.

What am I doing wrong?

Is my issue clear?

Comment: you restored the session from a saved one right? why are you running `global_variables_initializer` again? if you have some variables that you wish to initialize randomly and some to restore, you have to run only their initializers specifically.

Comment: I will try this, but if I don't run the initializer, I got an error saying the variable "weight" wasn't found.

Comment: If I only initialize some variables using `tf.initialize_variables` :
`FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value w1_1
  [[Node: w1_1/_8 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4_w1_1", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](w1_1)]]`.

Comment: Are you running this on a distributed setup? Why do you have multiple copies of the weight `w1` under `w1_1`? Can you post link to the github repo? It'll be easier to debug with the entire code.

Comment: No distributed system. Only GPU.

Answer (score 1):

```
 weights = 
    {
    '1': tf.Variable(sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0")), name='w1', trainable=False)
    }
```

I found out the answer. I needed to run the tensors to get the values. It seems obvious now.

edit 2 :

This way is not a good way to initialize tensors from other values because it will create 2 tensors with the same name when we restore and then create the tensor. Or, if different names, it will restore the variable from the past model and may try to optimize it later on. It is better to restore the variable in a previous session, store the values, then close the session, open a new one to create everything else.

```
 with tf.session() as sess: 
    weight1 = sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0"))

 tf.reset_default_graph() #this will eliminate the variables we restored

 with tf.session() as sess:
    weights = 
       {
       '1': tf.Variable(weight1 , name='w1-bis', trainable=False)
       }
...
```

We are now sure the restored variables are not a part of the graph.

Comment: Would by any chance help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215301/tensorflow-how-to-use-pretrained-weights-in-new-graph/50216044?noredirect=1#comment87449845_50216044)?

Comment: The issue is that I wanted to have untrainable variables. I didn't just want to restore the model, or the variables.

Comment: AFAIK the method works with both trainable and non-trainable variables.

Comment: I wanted to change previously trainables variable into non-trainable variables.* Sorry I didn't explain correctly.