# Tensorflow: how to use pretrained weights in new graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build an object detector with CNN using tensorflow with python framework. I would like to train my model to do just object recognition (classification) at first and then using several convolutional layers of the pretarined model train it to predict bounding boxes. I will need to replace fully connected layers and probably some last convolutional layers.  So, for this reason, I would like to know if it is possible to import **only** weights from tensorflow graph that was used to train object classifier to a newly defined graph that I will train to do object detection. So basically I would like to do something like this:

```
# here I initialize the new graph
conv_1=tf.nn.conv2d(in, weights_from_old_graph)
conv_2=tf.nn.conv2d(conv_1, weights_from_old_graph)
...
conv_n=tf.nn.nnconv2d(conv_n-1,randomly_initialized_weights)
fc_1=tf.matmul(conv_n, randomly_initalized_weights)
```

Comment: You may want to read this: [Choose Variables to Save and Restore](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#choose_variables_to_save_and_restore)

Comment: @Aechlys, oh yes, thank you. But I've seen this before and this method as I understand implies that I should save only those variables that I want to restore, but in order to experiment, I would like to save all variables and then chose which I want to use in the new graph.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use saver with no arguments to save the entire model.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", [3], initializer = tf.initializers.random_normal)
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", [5], initializer = tf.initializers.random_normal)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.save(sess, save_path='./test-case.ckpt')

    print(v1.eval())
    print(v2.eval())
saver = None
```

```
v1 = [ 2.1882825   1.159807   -0.26564872]
v2 = [0.11437789 0.5742971 ]
```

Then in the model you want to restore to certain values, pass a list of variable names you want to restore or a dictionary of `{"variable name": variable}` to the `Saver`.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [3], initializer= tf.initializers.random_normal)
b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", [3], initializer= tf.initializers.random_normal)
saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list={'v1': b1})

with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, "./test-case.ckpt")
  print(b1.eval())
  print(b2.eval())
```

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./test-case.ckpt
b1 = [ 2.1882825   1.159807   -0.26564872]
b2 = FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value b2
```

Comment: Oh my god, now I understand what they wrote in that tutorial... I feel a little bit stupid now, haha. Thank you very much)

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with Aechlys to restore variables. The problem is harder when we want to fix these variables. For example, we trained these variables and we want to use them in another model, but this time without training them (training new variables like in transfer-learning). You can see the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017707/tensorflow-restored-variables-seem-random/50141886#50141886).

Quick example:

```
 with tf.session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(pathToMeta)
    new_saver.restore(sess, pathToNonMeta) 

    weight1 = sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("w1:0")) 


 tf.reset_default_graph() #this will eliminate the variables we restored


 with tf.session() as sess:
    weights = 
       {
       '1': tf.Variable(weight1 , name='w1-bis', trainable=False)
       }
...
```

We are now sure the restored variables are not a part of the graph.

Comment: I'm quite far away from implementing this and, for now, I'm just speculating about this. But, the difference between your approach and Aechlys is that you restore graph of your old model and you take tensors from that graph and then you create the new graph using just numerical values of those tensors. In his approach, he defines the new graph and restores weights to it directly. So maybe it is just possible during definition of the new graph to set tf.get_variable(trainable=False)?

Comment: My assumtion is that the .meta file contains all defenitions of ops and variables in your graph, including properties of the variables. And the .data (the one with the biggest size) file contains numerical values and probably when you do restore it just initializes weights with the same name in graph with corresponding numerical values. But again, it is just speculations)

Comment: Indeed, the flag has been added since !