# fine-tuning with pre-trained weights in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use the convolutional layers of a pretrained network (VGG19) as a feature extractor and also be able to finetune the last layer during training. 
What i have is the vgg19.ckpt provided by tensorflow: 
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/vgg_19_2016_08_28.tar.gz
(found via https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim)

- The problem i have is: how do i only extract the specific weights for the layers that I am interested in from this ckpt file?
- So basically the first time i run the training it should load some of the weights of my graph from this ckpt and initialize the rest to random values, but the next time it should just load from the ckpt which contains the new weights (including the fixed weights).

Are there any examples that illustrate how to do this? (load specific weights from a ckpt file and also fine tune them during training in a new graph?)

Thank you!

J

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: how to use pretrained weights in new graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215301/tensorflow-how-to-use-pretrained-weights-in-new-graph)